# How to add text to tabs using `TabView[]`?

Tags: curated-data

This is the code I use `TabView[Map[#, {Url}] & /@ {Function1, 
   Function2, Function3}]`
to generate 3 different plots of a protein, but how can I add the names of the functions to the tab view, instead of showing number 1,2 and 3?

[image]
This image shows 3 different proteins.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
TabView[MapThread[#1 -> #2&, {{label1, label2, label3}, {plot1, plot2, plot3}}]]
```

[image]

perhaps?

Comment: The thing is that when using `MapThread[]`, the function needs a pair of arguments and my functions only have one argument. Here is my exact code: `TabView[MapThread[#, {Url1}] & /@ {ProteinColourBlue, 
   ProteinColourRed, ProteinColorYellow}]`. What I want is to put the title of the functions on the the tab button.

Comment: @LasdesNestor Just replace `{plot1, plot2, plot3}` with your plots, e.g. `Map[#, {Url}] & /@ {Function1, Function2, Function3}`